# Offline version history in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs, offline, version-control

I have a document that I'd like to edit offline (e.g. on a long airplane flight). I would like a way to restore changes that I'd made while offline, in the event that I accidentally delete a portion of the document. Normally, when I'm online, I can go into the version history (File > Version History) and pick an earlier version of the document; however, when I'm offline, this option is greyed-out. This happens even though I've enabled "Make available offline" and I have the Google Docs Offline extension in Chrome.

Is there a way to use version history when working offline in Google Docs?